# MySql how do I record cascade deletes on a self-referencing parent-child table using triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers, cascading-deletes

I have a **self-referencing parent-child table**, `tbl_projects`

`tbl_projects`

`id
project_name
parent_id`

If a record is a parent, its `parent_id` is `NULL`.
If it's a child, its `parent_id` is its parent's `id`.

I want to log `cascade deletes` to my log table, `tbl_log`.

I have triggers setup to insert stuff into `tbl_log` when something gets deleted from `tbl_project`

```
TRIGGER `tbl_project_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `tbl_project` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tbl_log (user_id, initiator, event) 
    VALUES (
        OLD.user_id, 
        OLD.initiator, 
        'record deleted by user on date etc.'
    );
END
```

My staight forward code above works just fine, **HOWEVER**, **it doesn't record cascade deletes**, meaning if I delete a parent, the children being deleted doesn't get recorded on `tbl_log`. I want to record it on `tbl_log`. Is there a built-in way to do it? How should I approach this?